# Finding the "killer" memory caching mechanism for Android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, out-of-memory, heap-memory

### Background

Android has a very limited max heap size, each device has a different max heap.

Some apps need the ability to cache things (usually images) in memory and not only on the internal/external storage.

Of course, there are plenty of [**nice tips**](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) regarding handling bitmaps and using as little memory as possible, but caching is also a needed thing.

### The problem

I've read many possible solutions for caching, but none offer a kind of caching that would be a killer caching solution. What I would like to have is a caching mechanism that has the next features:

1. Unlimited usage of the heap, without worrying about out of memory. App needs memory and there isn't enough free memory? so free some (unreferenced) items (and their keys).
2. Thread safety / concurrency.
3. Offer LRU based caching, so that items that were recently used have higher chance of staying.
4. Staying alive as much as possible (yet not cause any crashes). However, sadly, on Android, soft/weak references are GC-ed very quickly compared to Java.
5. Ability to handle objects that hide their real size. On Android, on API 10 and below, bitmaps didn't use the heap memory but were considered as such, so the VM couldn't know when to free them since it thought the use the same amount of memory as a single reference (4 bytes or so). This is why some solutions offer to artificially tell what is the size of each item, and what to do when it's time to remove it.

### Some good possible solutions

1. [**LruCache**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) - a class from API 12 (you can easily copy its code though).

   Advantages: #2 (?), #3, #5.

   Disadvantages: #1, #4, plus you need to copy its source code since it was presented on API 12.
2. **A hashmap with a soft/weak reference for its values**, as shown [here](http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_0230_TurboChargeYourUI-HowtomakeyourAndroidUIfastandefficient.pdf) on page 50, taken from [this lecture](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html).

   Advantages: #1 (but doesn't remove keys), #2 (need to use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html))

   Disadvantages: #3, #4, #5
3. [**MapMaker**](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) (available from [the guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)), which is like an advanced version of the previous solution.

   Advantages : #1, #2

   Disadvantages: #3, #4, #5
4. [Caching solutions](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=JavaCachingwithGuava.pdf&can=2&q=) via the guava library. Advantages and disadvantages are based on your choice. Not sure which configurations fits the needs the best, and if it works fine on Android. Sadly I can't succeed even compiling the library for Android.
5. [Android query](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) - not sure how it works. Seems very easy to use, but not sure about its advantages and disadvantages.

### Question

Does anybody know of a killer caching mechanism?

I care less about feature #5, as it's quite advanced and won't be so much needed in the future as more and more people have newer Android versions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165504

Comment: It is closed and dated, but this is a very important aspect for android performance which is not discussed enough, especially with large objects like Bitmaps. The Picasso library does automatic caching with images and you can extend their cache size if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see there is a practical prohibiting issue with #1. You cannot free objects that are referenced from other parts of the app; therefore, it is impossible to create a construct that frees memory on will.

The only solution I see is creating your own cache that supports LRU and is able to handle both weak and strong references. An item starts as a strong referenced thing and if not used for a while, or memory constraints enforce, you change it to a weak reference. This is not simple to create and fine tuning has to be done for sure in all applications.

Comment: no , you didn't understand it . i meant that you as a developer won't need to care about when to clear the cache (from items that are not referenced ) , or set a boundary about its size . it will do everything automatically , and use as much memory as possible , yet it will free memory when the app needs it (using soft/weak references , for example) .

Comment: I think this is exactly what I described :) The issue I'm raising is that you can apply heuristics for using strong and weak references wisely in the cache but you will still not have any influence on whether an object is freed or not. It depends on whether there is a strong reference path to it from a GC root. You will always have to handle OOM, you can only decrease the possibility you need to. Selecting good heuristics can make miracles.

Comment: no , if you use only weak/soft references for the objects you put into the cache , you aren't supposed to get out of memory exceptions when creating new objects (unless of course they have strong references), since the gc is suppose to clean them when it notices there isn't enough memory to hold everything . it's a very safe way , but sadly android releases such objects very often , even if there is enough memory .

Comment: This is what I tried to explain. The whole thing depends on whether your application behaves well or not. Does it let unused cached objects free or does it keep strong references to them. Weak references alone are not going to ensure anything. You can still receive OOMs. And exactly because Android frees weak referenced objects too eagerly, you should employ some heuristics and keep strong references in the cache to the objects you want to keep there. But if the memory saturates, the cache should intelligently start changing to weak references. This is very complex to implement correctly.

Comment: well that's why i've asked for a good solution for android . because it is complex and i don't think there is a good solution that i could find . some solutions (like the guava library) i can't even try out because they don't work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a more general solution, but if you're mainly focused on images, take a look at [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader). I've been using it for a while and it works very well for what I need. When initializing it you can tell it to use an LRUCache and tell it what % of free memory to use.

As a side note, [HttpResponseCache](https://github.com/candrews/HttpResponseCache) makes caching data from a server very, very nice.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong , but the problem with it is that it's bounded . it also won't free memory when needed , only when it passes the maximal amount of memory i've given it . so it's like solution #1 i've mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Android BitMap Cache, which is a heavily improved version of LruCache.

http://www.senab.co.uk/2013/01/24/android-bitmapcache-v2-1/

Comment: nice,  but according to the sample with the gridView of this library , it doesn't have feature #4 , which means that images are freed very early , so the memory cache is rarely used . plus, the sample has bugs of not showing some images at all  , and this solution is only for bitmaps.